# ElasticSearch NEST Completion Suggest Filter

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Currently working on a project involving a vehicle database.

We have set up some filters for the end users to select, such as chassis, transmission, price. Which works as intended
Now we are trying to implement a autocomplete feature in the search field. Since the simple query string will require a complete modelname and or brandname, I have looked into completion and that works for an unfinished brand name ie: "tesl" will suggest the respective Tesla models.

**What I'm struggling with is getting the suggestions within the specified query.**

Thanks!

Solution:
Not sure if this is the correct way to solve it, but I just ran the main query with the suggested ids to get the full payload to get all the data i need for the text search.

```
var result = await _client.SearchAsync<Models.VehicleModel>(descriptor => descriptor
                .Index("vehiclemodel")
                .Query(
                    q => 
                             q
                                 .Terms(t => t
                                     .Name("ModelName")
                                     .Field("modelName")
                                     .Terms(searchArguments.Models)
                                 )
                         &&
                             q
                                 .Terms(t => t
                                     .Name("BrandName")
                                     .Field("brandName")
                                     .Terms(searchArguments.Brands)
                                 )
                         
                         &&
                         q
                             .Range(t => t
                                 .Name("Price")
                                 .Field("modelMinimumPrice")
                                 .GreaterThanOrEquals(searchArguments.MinPrice)
                                 .LessThanOrEquals(searchArguments.MaxPrice)
                             )
                         &&

                         q
                             .SimpleQueryString(c => c
                                 .Name("textquery")
                                 .Query(searchArguments.Query)
                                 .Boost(2)
                                 .Fields(f => f
                                     .Field(p => p.BrandName + "^2")
                                     .Field(p => p.ModelName + "^2")
                                     .Field(p => p.EnergySource)
                                     .Field("*")
                                 )
                             )
```

```
      public async Task<dynamic> GetModelSearchSuggestions(SearchArguments searchArguments = default)
        {
            var result = await _client.SearchAsync<dynamic>(s => s
            .Index("vehiclemodel")
            .Suggest(su => su
                .Completion("searchsuggest", cs => cs
                    .Field("suggest")
                    .Prefix(searchArguments.Query)
                    .Fuzzy(f => f
                        .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
                    )
                )
                )
            );

            return result.Suggest;
        }
```

```
            mappingDescriptor
                .Properties(p => p
                .Completion(cp => cp
                    .Name("suggest")
                    .Analyzer("standard")
                    .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
                    )
                .Text(t => t.Name("modelName").Fielddata(true))
                .Text(t => t.Name("brandName").Fielddata(true))
                );
```

Comment: Could you share your index mapping? That may help with finding what is wrong.

Comment: I have added the mapping. Found a way around it. By running the main query with the suggested ids. Let me know if you see any obvious mistakes. Thanks!